# != operator and file streams

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    ifstream file0( "file0.txt" );
    ifstream file1( "file1.txt" );

    if (file0 != file1) {
        cout << "What is being compared?" << endl;
    }

}
```

If the above code, what is being compared in the conditional? I believe it is pointer values but I am unable to find supporting evidence.

Thanks!

Comment: A step towards "the pointers are being compared" can be taken by testing for equality. Should not cout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When doing a comparison on an ifstream the `operator void*` will be called. If you are using visual studio you can see this if you choose to see the disassembly of the code.

The operator can be found [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios/operator_voidpt/).
As you can see mentioned:

> The pointer returned is not intended to be referenced, it just indicates success when none of the error flags are set.

So if both ifstreams fail, they will be equal. If they succeed (although I am not sure where the pointer value comes from) they will **not** be equal [this has been tested on VS].

Comment: Say, how does the compiler know to choose operator void*() over operator bool()? What defines the precedence?

Comment: @chris: I was actually thinking about the same thing. That is beyond my knowledge though..

Comment: Streams don't have an `operator bool`. The returned `void*` is implicitly convertible to bool in boolean contexts (`if (std::cin)...`).

Comment: @UncleBens 
Since C++11, streams have `operator bool`. However no ambiguity for compiler because `operator bool` is `explicit`. e.g. developer has to request `bool` value to use `operator bool`. For instance: `if ((bool)file0)`