# operator precedence (void* before bool?)

Tags: c++, operators, filestream, iostream, operator-precedence

When answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4294285/238902) I made some research which really confuses me.

I noticed that two ifstreams that succesfully open are not equal but two ifstreams that fail are.
At first i checked cplusplus.com. The [`operator !`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios/operatornot/) returns the status of the badbit and failbit. I think that the opposite of this would still be to return the status of these two bits, but flipped.

- **Wrong**, because two succesful calls are not equal.

So then I figured it was an `operator bool` somewhere that would return something. So I tried to backtrack from ifstream and found the `istream::operator bool()`, which is returning `_Ok`.

- **Still wrong however**, this doesn't seem to be called at all (and couldn't be, since the two successful calls are still not equal).

So I changed my approach and checked the disassembly from Visual Studio. And what do I find?
`if (file0 != file1) {` doesn't call the `operator bool()`, **but rather the `operator void* ()`** (or really `__imp_std::ios_base::operator void *`).

So the questions I have are..

- Shouldn't any `operator bool ()` found be called before trying to casting it to pointer values?
- Is it some `operator bool()` I missed that in turn is calling the `operator void*` ?
- Is this some optimizing that I don't understand?
- Or am I completely wrong in that C++ *actually thinks* that `void*` is a better match than `bool` in this comparison?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.) You cannot overload multiple times but with different return types.
2.) Yes, `operator!` returns the badbit/failbit, but `operator!` is something entirely different from `operator!=`, which is the one you are using.

Comment: Ah, yes.. I see. Thanks, I'm getting tired here I feel. I have a follow up question on this then :) Maybe you can answer [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4294873/238902 "define both operator void* and operator bool") as well..?

Comment: However.. The ifstream is actually calling operator void* and not operator!=.