# define both operator void* and operator bool

Tags: c++, operators, ambiguity

I tried creating a class with one `operator bool` and one `operator void*`, but the compiler says they are ambigous. Is there some way I can explain to the compiler what operator to use or can I not have them both?

```
class A {
public:
    operator void*(){
        cout << "operator void* is called" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    operator bool(){
        cout << "operator bool is called" << endl;
        return true;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a1, a2;
    if (a1 == a2){
        cout << "hello";
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you actually need both? `operator void*` functions as a slightly safer `operator bool` because there are fewer bad things you can accidentally do with a `void*`. Also google for safe bool idiom which minimizes abuse even further (by defining a `operator pointer-to-member` if I'm not mistaken).

Comment: Actually, it was in reference to an answer I provided for `ifstream`. I was wondering why the operator void* was called prior to operator bool, but when I did this it was ambigous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could call the operator directly.

```
int main()
{
    A a1, a2;
    if (static_cast<bool>(a1) == static_cast<bool>(a2)){
        cout << "hello";
    }
}
```

In this case, though, it looks like you should define `operator==()` and not depend on conversions.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be needed in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4294285/238902). How does `ifstream` resolve this?

Comment: .. because I have seen the `operator bool()` in istream, and in that thread, the `operator void*` is called.

Comment: accepted though, since `operator==()` resolved the issue (and let's me have both the conversion operators)

Comment: @Default: I doubt library streams have both. AFAIK, they only have `operator void*` and in C++0x they will have `explicit operator bool` instead.

Comment: @Default: You can test with `typedef std::basic_ios<char, std::char_traits<char> > bios; bool (bios::*p)()const = &bios::operator bool; void* (bios::*v)()const = &bios::operator void*;` and see if both actually exist.

Comment: @Uncle: thanks for your help. I'm upvoting your two last answers as my token of appreciation :)

Answer (score 8):

The problem here is that you're defining `operator bool` but from the sounds of it what you want is `operator ==`. Alternatively, you can explicitly cast to `void *` like this:

```
if ((void *)a1 == (void *)a2) {
    // ...
}
```

... but that's really bizarre. Don't do that. Instead, define your `operator ==` like this inside `class A`:

```
bool operator==(const A& other) const {
    return /* whatever */;
}
```